# Selecting a row in a Kendo UI Grid using cypress

Tags: kendo-grid, cypress

I am using Cypress to test an application that uses Kendo Grid.

I have successfully using the following code to select the first record in the grid:

cy.get('#equiptmentGrid').invoke('getKendoGrid').invoke("select", 'tr:eq(0)')

Is there a way to select the last record in the Kendo Grid

Answer (score 1):

Try using `last()` command from cypress. In the below example I have a kendo grid displaying records displaying in the Grid. The below test code will get the last `tr` then using `find()` command, find the `td`and get the "Some Text" as below;

```
 cy.get('#grid > div > table > tbody >tr').last().find('td').invoke("text").should('include', 'Some Text');
```

If could you please post the `html`, I will try to figure the way to get the last record